# Opening link generates Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open'of object 'Workbooks' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file which contains macros & takes daily Open Interest data from CME (Chicago Mercantile Exchange) Group, USA; and updates an internal database which then updates the line charts.

This website updates the data twice a day, Preliminary & Final.
https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/metals-volume.html
The macro has functions to check final data first, if found, it updates the data otherwise it looks for preliminary data & updates it.

The file has a sheet called "Main" where we write the date in a cell. This sheet has two buttons (two macros, one udpates the data for individual date & second updates the data if data from multiple dates needs updating).
The file has a sheet called "Links" which contains the URL in parts to download desired workbook/sheets to the file, then it copies the specific data into separate data sheets inside the file for each instrument, which is used to make/update the Open Interest line charts for each individual financial instrument.

These macros are working for others using different Windows & Excel versions but they stopped working in my three latptops. Couple of laptops has Windows 10 & Excel 2016, other laptop has Windows 11 & Excel 2021.

When I run the macro by pressing a button from sheet "Main" macro starts & file goes to unlimited processing.
Accidentally I found a solution. I press ESC button few times, macro runs & updates the data/line charts.
Macros are unblocked & fully enabled from Trust Center.

Full code.

```vb
Sub download_data2()
    Dim lastdate, report_date As Date
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Main").Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    
    'getting todays links
    report_date = Sheets("Main").Cells(1, 3).Value
    extr_date = Format(Year(report_date), "00") & Format(Month(report_date), "00") & Format(Day(report_date), "00")
    Sheets("Links").Cells(2, 1).Value = extr_date
    
    'links for final data
    link_metal = Sheets("Links").Cells(1, 1).Value & extr_date & Sheets("Links").Cells(3, 1).Value & Sheets("Links").Cells(5, 1).Value
    link_fx = Sheets("Links").Cells(1, 1).Value & extr_date & Sheets("Links").Cells(4, 1).Value & Sheets("Links").Cells(5, 1).Value
    link_oil = Sheets("Links").Cells(1, 1).Value & extr_date & Sheets("Links").Cells(9, 1).Value & Sheets("Links").Cells(5, 1).Value
    link_irv = Sheets("Links").Cells(1, 1).Value & extr_date & Sheets("Links").Cells(10, 1).Value & Sheets("Links").Cells(5, 1).Value
    link_eqvol = Sheets("Links").Cells(1, 1).Value & extr_date & Sheets("Links").Cells(11, 1).Value & Sheets("Links").Cells(5, 1).Value
           
    wb_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Metals").Range("A1:X5000").Clear
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Metals").Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("FX").Range("A1:X5000").Clear
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("FX").Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Energy").Range("A1:X5000").Clear
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Energy").Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
    
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Range("A1:X5000").Clear
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Equity Volume").Range("A1:X5000").Clear
    Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Equity Volume").Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
        
    'download final data
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
    Workbooks.Open link_metal
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Metals").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
    'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
    'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
    Workbooks.Open link_fx
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("FX").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
    'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
    Workbooks.Open link_oil
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Energy").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
    'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    'Application.Wait (Now + 0.00011)
    Workbooks.Open link_irv
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
    'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
    Workbooks.Open link_eqvol
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Equity Volume").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
    'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'check if there is final data
     If Sheets("Metals").Cells(7, 1).Value = "" Then
       
    'download preliminary data
       link_metal = Replace(link_metal, "reportType=F", "reportType=P")
       link_fx = Replace(link_fx, "reportType=F", "reportType=P")
       link_oil = Replace(link_oil, "reportType=F", "reportType=P")
       link_irv = Replace(link_irv, "reportType=F", "reportType=P")
       link_eqvol = Replace(link_eqvol, "reportType=F", "reportType=P")
       
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       
       'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
       Workbooks.Open link_metal
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets(1).Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Metals").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
       'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close False

       'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
       Workbooks.Open link_fx
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("FX").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
       'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close False
           
       'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
       Workbooks.Open link_oil
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Energy").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
       'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close False
       
       'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
       Workbooks.Open link_irv
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
       'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close False
       
       'Application.Wait (Now + 0.000011)
       Workbooks.Open link_eqvol
        last_row = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        last_column = Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        last_column = Split(Cells(, last_column).Address, "$")(1)
        Sheets("VOI Totals Report").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row).Copy Workbooks(wb_name).Sheets("Equity Volume").Range("A5:" & last_column & last_row)
       'Workbooks("voiProductsViewExport").Close False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close False
              
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     End If
     
     'check if no data at all for this date
     If Sheets("Metals").Cells(7, 1).Value = "" Then
        
        Exit Sub
     End If
     
    'updating the tabs
    'Gold
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Gold Futures" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Gold", "Gold OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
    
    'Silver
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Silver" & "*" & "Future*" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Silver", "Silver OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
    
    'Copper
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Copper Future*" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Copper", "Copper OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
    
    'Iron Ore
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Iron Ore" & "*" & "(TSI) Future*" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Iron Ore", "Iron Ore OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
    
    'Palladium
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Palladium Future*" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Palladium", "Palladium OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
        
    'Platinum
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Metals").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Metals").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Platinum Future*" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_met("Platinum", "Platinum OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
                
    'updating oil
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Energy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Energy").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Crude Oil Futures" Then
            met_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_energy("Oil", "Oil OI Chart", met_pos, report_date)
    met_pos = Empty
    
    'Henry Hub Natural Gas
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Energy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Energy").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Henry Hub Natural Gas Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_energy("Henry Hub Natural Gas", "Henry Hub Natural Gas Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'EUR
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Euro FX Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EUR", "EUR Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'GBP
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "British Pound Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("GBP", "GBP Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'JPY
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Japanese Yen Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("JPY", "JPY Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'CHF
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Swiss Franc Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("CHF", "CHF Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'AUD
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Australian Dollar Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("AUD", "AUD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'NZD
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "New Zealand Dollar Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("NZD", "NZD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'CAD
    For T = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("FX").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Canadian Dollar Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("CAD", "CAD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    '10-Year T-Note Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "10-Year T-Note Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("10Y TNF", "10Y TNF Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    '2-Year T-Note Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "2-Year T-Note Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("2Y TNF", "2Y TNF Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    '5-Year T-Note Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "5-Year T-Note Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("5Y TNF", "5Y TNF Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'Eurodollar Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Eurodollar Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("EURODOLLAR", "EURODOLLAR Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'U.S. Treasury Bond Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "U.S. Treasury Bond Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("US Treas Bond", "US Treas Bond Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
        
    'Ultra U.S. Treasury Bond Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "Ultra U.S. Treasury Bond Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_irv("Ultra US Treas Bond", "Ultra US Treas Bond Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
        
    'E-Mini Russell 2000 Index Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "E-mini  Russell 2000 Index Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_eqvol("E-Mini Rus2000 Index", "E-Mini Rus2000 Index Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
        
    'E-Mini Dow ($5) Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "E-mini Dow ($5) Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_eqvol("E-mini Dow 5", "E-mini Dow 5 Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'E-Mini Nasdaq-100 Futures
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "E-mini Nasdaq-100 Futures*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_eqvol("E-mini Nasdaq 100", "E-mini Nasdaq 100 Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    'E-mini S&P 500 Future
    For T = 7 To Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(T, 1).Value Like "E-mini S&P 500 Future*" Then
            fx_pos = T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next T
    Call Tab_Chart_Update_eqvol("E-mini SP 500", "E-mini SP 500 Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    fx_pos = Empty
    
    ' FX update section
    ' AUDJPY
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Australian Dollar/Japanese Yen Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("AUDJPY", "AUDJPY Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'EURGBP
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Euro/British Pound Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EURGBP", "EURGBP Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'EURJPY
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Euro/Japanese Yen Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EURJPY", "EURJPY Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'EURCHF
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Euro/Swiss Franc Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EURCHF", "EURCHF Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'GBPJPY
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "British Pound/Japanese Yen Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("GBPJPY", "GBPJPY Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'AUDNZD
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Australian Dollar/New Zealand Dollar Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("AUDNZD", "AUDNZD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'EURAUD
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Euro/Australian Dollar Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EURAUD", "EURAUD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    'EURCAD
    'For t = 7 To Sheets("FX").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Sheets("FX").Cells(t, 1).Value Like "Euro/Canadian Dollar Future*" Then
    'fx_pos = t
    'Exit For
    'End If
    'Next t
    'Call Tab_Chart_Update_fx("EURCAD", "EURCAD Chart", fx_pos, report_date)
    'fx_pos = Empty
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function Tab_Chart_Update_met(sh_name, ch_name, met_row, report_date)
    If met_row = Empty Then Exit Function
    lastdate = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1)
    If lastdate = report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
    End If
    If lastdate < report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Metals").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value = report_date
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    End If
    
    'Updating the OI charts
    For i = 2 To 12
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 1)
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 3)
    Next

End Function

Function Tab_Chart_Update_fx(sh_name, ch_name, fx_row, report_date)
    If fx_row = Empty Then Exit Function
    lastdate = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value
    If lastdate = report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 6).Value
    End If
    If lastdate < report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("FX").Cells(fx_row, 6).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value = report_date
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    End If
    
    'Updating the OI charts
    For i = 2 To 12
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 1)
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 3)
    Next
End Function

Function Tab_Chart_Update_energy(sh_name, ch_name, met_row, report_date)
    If met_row = Empty Then Exit Function
    lastdate = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1)
    If lastdate = report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
    End If
    If lastdate < report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Energy").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value = report_date
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    End If
    
    'Updating the OI charts
    For i = 2 To 12
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 1)
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 3)
    Next
End Function

Function Tab_Chart_Update_irv(sh_name, ch_name, met_row, report_date)
    If met_row = Empty Then Exit Function
    lastdate = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1)
    If lastdate = report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
    End If
    If lastdate < report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Interest Rate Volume").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value = report_date
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    End If
    
    'Updating the OI charts
    For i = 2 To 12
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 1)
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 3)
    Next
End Function

Function Tab_Chart_Update_eqvol(sh_name, ch_name, met_row, report_date)
    If met_row = Empty Then Exit Function
    lastdate = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1)
    If lastdate = report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
    End If
    If lastdate < report_date Then
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 8).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 7).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Equity Volume").Cells(met_row, 6).Value
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).Value = report_date
        Sheets(sh_name).Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    End If
    
    'Updating the OI charts
    For i = 2 To 12
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 1)
        Sheets(ch_name).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(sh_name).Cells(14 - i, 3)
    Next
End Function

Sub get_all_up_to_date()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim startdate, mem_date As Date
    Dim day_back As Integer
    day_back = Sheets("Links").Cells(15, 1).Value
    startdate = Sheets("Gold").Cells(2, 1).Value
    If startdate > Date Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
    If Date - startdate > day_back Then startdate = Date - day_back
    Do While startdate <= Date - 2
        If Weekday(startdate) <> 7 And Weekday(startdate) <> 1 Then
            Sheets("Main").Cells(1, 3).Value = startdate
            Call download_data2
        End If
        'MsgBox ("")
        startdate = startdate + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I ran the macro line by line using the F8 key, it gets stuck on line `Workbooks.Open link_metal`.

I found some solutions

1. Disabling the Automation security before Opening the workbook & then reseting it to orginal.
2. Adding Application.EnableEvents=False to code to stop firing the event handlers from other function of same workbook.
3. Copying Macro code in ThisWorkBook, instead of Module or file

Commenting out all lines that manipulate `Application.DisplayAlerts` or `Application.ScreenUpdating` gave me

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open'of object 'Workbooks' failed

Comment: “Gets stuck” is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run the code.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. There is no error message at all, thats why i wrote in title "Gets stuck". Had there been an error message, i would have mentioned here clearly.

Comment: So when it hangs there's no error, and the execution just stops at the `Open` line and never continues?  I've seen an `Open` fail, but typically you'll get a pop-up or error message.  When it does that, if you stop the code and try to open the link manually via `File >> Open >> paste in the URL` does it open, and if not, what happens?

Comment: Yes, macro code stops at line (Workbooks.Open link_metal) without any error, seems code try to access the URL to download the data sheets but doesn't get through. When i press ESC button twice only then it pops ups a window named "Downloading" with the URL address written as message & downloads/updates the data of an assett class. Again, code stops for unlimited period without any error message & again i need to repeat this ESC button hack for total 8 times, to completely update the file.
This file is working for some people without this ESC hack, whats wrong in my case? thats the question

Comment: ESC Key is skipping some process from macro code which causes this issue, thats why file gets updated. I want to fix that part of macro code by deletion or subsitution, whatever wroks for me.

Comment: Comment out all lines that  manipulate `Application.DisplayAlerts` or `Application.ScreenUpdating`. What happens then?

Comment: @GSerg I tried your solution & it gave me this error .... Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Open'of object 'Workbooks' failed

Comment: Well there is your actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the lines `Workbooks.Open link_xxx` with `OpenWorkbookURL link_xxx` and add this sub

```vb
Sub OpenWorkbookURL(url As String)
    Dim oStream, oHTTP, xlsname As String
    xlsname = "~download.xls"
    Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With oHTTP
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)"
        .Send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            With oStream
                .Open
                .Type = 1
                .Write oHTTP.ResponseBody
                .SaveToFile xlsname, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
                .Close
            End With
            Workbooks.Open xlsname, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```